# YouTube keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: youtube, keyboard-shortcuts

I just found out if you type <kbd>j</kbd> when watching a YouTube video, it lapses back about 10-20 seconds, depending on the video, I think.

What are the keyboard shortcuts when using YouTube?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's at the bottom of the [Screen reader support page](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189278):

```
Keyboard shortcut           Function
------------------------------------
O                           To jump to the beginning of the flash player

Spacebar                    Play/Pause when the seek bar is selected.
                            Activate a button if a button has focus

Play/Pause Media Key
on keyboards                Play / Pause

Stop Media Key
on keyboards                Stop

Next Track Media Key
on keyboards                Moves to the next track in a play/list

Left/Right arrow on
the seek bar                Seek backward/forward 5 seconds

Ctrl+left/ctrl+right
arrow on the seek bar       Seek backward/forward 10 seconds

Home/End on the seek bar    Seek to the beginning/last seconds of the video

Up/Down arrow on the
seek bar                    Increase/Decrease volume 5%

Numbers 1 to 9
(not on the numeric pad)
on the seek bar             Seek to the 10% to 90% of the video

Number 0
(not on the numeric pad)
on the seek bar             Seek to the beginning of the video
```

Indeed it's very hard to find. They ought to make a dedicated page for this.

Comment: Considering there are already 6 answers, while really all their information should be contained in a single post, wouldn't it be a good idea to make this post a community wiki?

Answer (score 16):

In addition to [Zom-B's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/25420/5062),

```
Keyboard shortcut           Function
------------------------------------------------
J                           10 seconds backwards
K                           Pause / Play
L                           10 seconds forward
```

[Source](http://lifehacker.com/5899420/press-j-and-l-to-skip-12-seconds-back-and-forward-in-youtube-videos).

Answer (score 11):

In addition to other answers:

```
Keyboard shortcut           Function
------------------------------------------------
M                           Mute / Unmute
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Keyboard shortcut           Function
------------------------------------------------
F                           full screen
```

Comment: Doesn't work...

Answer (score 5):

```
Keyboard shortcut           Function
------------------------------------------------
<                           Slower (3 levels)
>                           Speed up (3 levels)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Keyboard shortcut           Function
------------------------------------------------ 
Pause then Left/Right       Framestep
```

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>?</kbd> or  <kbd>shift + ?</kbd> for a list of keyboard shortcuts (may only be on html5)

Comment: Does the ? trick actually work on YouTube at all?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal I tried in chrome, and it's shift + ?, not just ?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to other answers:

```
Keyboard shortcut           Function
------------------------------------------------
Left followed by Up         Snake game :o)
```

Comment: Simply pressing up does not work. I believe it does work if you press any combination of left/right and then up/down.

Answer (score 2):

```
Keyboard shortcut           Function
------------------------------------------------
Shift+N                     Next video
Shift+P                     Previous video
```

Jumps to the next or previous video in a playlist. On a single video, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> will play the next suggested video.

Answer (score 1):

Note: These shortcuts will only work when the video player is in focus. To move the focus try pressing the spacebar to pause and then play the video.

- Toggle play/pause the video

  - k or Spacebar
- Go back 5 seconds

  - Left arrow
- Go back 10 seconds

  - j
- Go forward 5 seconds

  - Right arrow
- Go forward 10 seconds

  - l
- Skip to a particular section of the video (e.g., 5 goes to the video midpoint)

  - Numbers 1-9 (not the keypad numbers)
- Restart video

  - 0 (not the keypad number)
- Go to Full Screen mode

  - f
- Exit Full Screen mode

  - Escape
- Go to beginning of video

  - Home
- Go to end of video

  - End
- Increase volume 5%

  - Up arrow
- Decrease volume 5%

  - Down arrow
- Increase speed

  - Shift+> (may not work in all browsers) or Shift+. (period)
- Decrease speed

  - Shift+< (may not work in all browsers)  or Shift+, (comma)
- Move forward 1 frame when video is paused

  - . (period)
- Move backward 1 frame when video is paused

  - , (comma)
- Mute/unmute video

  - m
- Turn captions on/off

  - c
- Cycle through options for caption background color

  - b
- Move to the previous video in a playlist

  - Shift+p
- Move to the next video in a playlist

  - Shift+n

Additional References:

- https://sites.google.com/a/umich.edu/going-google/accessibility/google-keyboard-shortcuts---youtube
- https://digiwonk.gadgethacks.com/how-to/30-keyboard-shortcuts-you-should-be-using-youtube-0161382/