# In YouTube is there anyway to select specific time?

Tags: youtube

For example if you just missed something and want to rewind 3 seconds is there an easier way than using the scroll bar?

Comment: the `#t=xhymzs` also works, where x= no of hours, y= no of minutes, z=no of secods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the scrollbar selected the easiest thing to do is use the left and right arrow keys to jump back and forward around 3 to 5 seconds.

Check out [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25419/youtube-keyboard-shortcuts) for a complete list of shortcut keys.

Comment: You can also use numbers 0,1,2 to 9 to skip respectively to 0%, 10%, 20%, etc. of playback.